# Map in QGIS is displayed tilted?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, epsg

CRS is wgs 84 epsg:4326

Still the map and the data on screen is showing tilted.

[image]

Comment: Open a new project, then add the basemap first then add your shapefile on top of it and see if this can solve the problem.

Comment: Because WGS84 works this way when used for higher latitudes. Change your CRS to a projected one and the distortion should be gone.

Comment: @Erik Thanks! Your solution worked.